# Why alert() works 3 times?

Tags: javascript

I have part of code where `alert("wrong word!")` repeats 3 times and then stops:

```js
    let input = prompt("What do you wanna to translate?", "");
    let words = [{
      en_word : "apple",
      your_word : "some_word"
    }, {
      en_word : "grapes",
      your_word : "some_word"
    }, {
      en_word : "pineapple",
      your_word : "some_word"
    }];
    for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
      if (input == words[i].your_word) {
        alert(words[i].en_word);
      } else {
        alert("wrong word!");
      }
    };
```

Why is this happening, and how to fix it?

Comment: because the condition is checked 3 times

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. This is a more cleaner approach. the moment you find the match, break the loop.

```
let  input = prompt('What do you wanna to translate?','');  
let words = [                         
    {en_word: "apple",  your_word: "яблуко"},
    {en_word: "grapes",  your_word: "виноград"},
    {en_word: "pineapple",  your_word: "ананас"}
];

let isFound = false;  
for(let i = 0; i < words.length; i++){
    if(input == words[i].your_word){
        alert(words[i].en_word);
        isFound = true;
        break;
    }
}

if(!isFound) alert("wrong word!");
```

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the alert is within a loop and the condition is checked 3 times.

Here, I slightly modified the code.

Use a `FLAG` in condition block in `for` loop as well as to detect if the word is not found. The advantage of this is that we can stop executing it once we found the match. You can use `break` instead if you want. But since you're using else condition, a flag is required.

To clarify, the last one is a ternary operator, which check whether the word is found or not. If not, it alerts *wrong word*

```js
let  input = prompt('What do you wanna to translate?','');  
let words = [                         
    {en_word: "apple",  your_word: "яблуко"},
    {en_word: "grapes",  your_word: "виноград"},
    {en_word: "pineapple",  your_word: "ананас"}
];

let FLAG = false;
for(i=0; i<words.length && !FLAG; i++){
  if(input == words[i].your_word){
    FLAG = !FLAG;
    alert(words[i].en_word);
  }
}
!FLAG?alert("wrong word"):void(0);
```